# Importing multiple text files into multiple tables using ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q:    I have multiple text files in a folder named xyz, and i have created a new database in sqlserver which does not having any tables .Here my problem is to import all those text files into new database according to the text file named tables using ssis package .can anyone knows please tell me the steps.

A:   `Step 1: Use foreach loop iterator to pick all files in the specific folder.`

`Step 2: By using script task get the column name from text file and create the tables in you database. Keep the table name in the SSIS variable.`

```
Step 3: Choose any destination task and insert the data into the newly created tables.
```

I used `foreach` loop container and selected the path of text files .in step 2 am unable to write the script for the column import .I have couple of text files named employee having columns `id ,name` and another one department having `deptno ,location` . Actually am a beginner to `sql server and ssis` too.can anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at [this link](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx), this will show you how to pick the files up
2. Within the `ForEach Loop container`, you will have a `dataflow task`.
3. The source will be a `Flat File Source` which uses a `Flat File Connection Manager`.  The `flat file connection manager` will have an `expression` for the `connectionstring` which will be the variable populated in step 1.
4. The destination will be an `OLE DB Destination`, which will point to your table.

**NOTE**: It might be easier to get the basic flow set up, with the FlatFile connection manager etc hard coded to one of the files.  This will allow you to get the process working, and then you can introduce the ForEach loop and the variable/expression to make the process flexible.