# Import data into multiple table from multiple csv file in sql server

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have created a database in sql server. It has three tables. I have three csv files for these tables(all the csv files are in same folder). Data format is same in both csv and db table.

Currently I am using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to load data from csv files. But in this way  I can only insert data into one table. I have to repeat the same task multiple times.

Is there any way to insert data into multiple table from multiple csv files in single query?

Thanks

Comment: use bcp.exe command line tool, or use bulk insert command.  you can't do it in a single command, but it can be automated so run as a script as opposed to wizard.

Comment: You can do it using SSIS Transaformation tasks

Comment: I never worker with SSIS. Can you please explain how can I achieve this using SSIS? Thanks @Srini131

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872747/importing-multiple-text-files-into-multiple-tables-using-ssis Go through this link